# React/Javascript - saving values from local csv into useState / useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, d3.js, react-hooks

I'm trying to load the data from a csv into useState via a useEffect state. But I can't get it to work.

My csv contains data like this:

```
  Date             Value1   Value2 
  2020/7/20        1        4              
  2020/7/21        2        8 
  2020/7/22        3        10
  2020/7/23        4        12
  2020/7/24        5        67
  2020/7/25        6        10
```

And I'm trying to get the data in a `useState` via `useEffect` like this:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import csvFile from '../data/Data.csv';


const Linechart = (props) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]); 

  useEffect(()=>{
     if (data.length > 0) {
       drawChart();
     } else {

      getCSVData();
    }
   ,[]);

    // gets csv data from csv
  const getCSVData = async () => {
    let tempData = [];
      await d3.csv(csvFile,

      function(d){
        tempData.push({date: d3.timeParse("%Y/%m/%d")(d.Date), value1: parseFloat(d.Value1), value2: parseFloat(d.Value2)}),    
      } 
    )
      setData(tempData);

      console.log("data is: ", data.date)
      console.log("value1 is: ", data.value1)
      console.log("value2 is: ", data.value2)
  }
```

For some reason it does not want to work. I get the following error:

```
attr.js:30 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…".
```

It seems to get stuck at `tempData.push`. I have never used this `.push` (I'm very new to both React and Javascript). Can someone help me fix this maybe?

The data is used for a d3 visualization, here is the full code to create the linechart:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
 import csvFile from '../data/Data.csv';


const Linechart = (props) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const {width, height } = props;

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (data.length > 0) {
      drawChart();
    } else {

      getCSVData();
    }},[data]);

   console.log(data)

    // gets csv data from a csv
  const getCSVData = async () => {
    let tempData = [];
      await d3.csv(csvFile,

      function(d){

        tempData.push({date: d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y")(d.Date), value1: parseFloat(d.Value1), value2: parseFloat(d.Value2)});
      }

    )
    console.log(tempData)
      setData(tempData);
      console.log("data is: ",data.date)
  }

const drawChart = () => {

    // create the chart area
    const svg = d3.select('.svg-canvas')
  svg.selectAll("*").remove();

// Add X axis --> it is a date format
    var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.csv(data, function(d) { return d.date; }))
      .range([ 0, width ]);
      
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));


    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return + d.value1; })])
      .range([ height, 0 ]);
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // set line coordinates
    const line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
      
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.value1) })

    // Add the line
    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", line)
 }

return (
    <div>
     <svg className="svg-canvas" width="1000px" height="600px" />


    </div>
    )

}

export default Linechart;
```

The error comes from the `drawChart` function as it is not receiving the right data

Comment: wdym by stuck, can you please elaborate more ... Do you see any errors?

Comment: Create Minimal reproductive example. Without your code, we cannot tell you what you are doing wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DecPK I added the full code now :)

Comment: I've copy/pasted your code into a running sandbox and there are no errors. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-javascript-saving-values-from-local-csv-into-usestate-useeffect-bc7s64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `.push()` like that, you need to wrap all the values in a object and then push them to the `tempData` array. After that you will be able to set the state with the new array.

```
tempData.push( { date: d3.timeParse("%Y/%m/%d")(d.Date), value1: parseFloat(d.Value1), value2: parseFloat(d.Value2) } );
setData(tempData);
```

Now you will have state which is going to be array with one item on the 0 index which is going to be object with properties.

```
[ 0: { date: ... , value1: ... , value2: ... } ]
```

After that when you need to access your data you have to loop over the array.

```
data.map((currentEl) => {
  console.log(currentEl)
  console.log(currentEl.date)
  console.log(currentEl.value1)
  console.log(currentEl.value2)
})
```

Another way yo do this is to set your state to object,

```
const [data, setData] = useState({date: '', value1: '', value2: ''});  

const tempData = { date: d3.timeParse("%Y/%m/%d")(d.Date), value1: parseFloat(d.Value1), value2: parseFloat(d.Value2) }  

setData(tempData);  
console.log(data.date)
console.log(data.value1)
console.log(data.value2)
```

Comment: Hi! A yeah you mean the {} ? I added those, forgot them in my example. But I also added the whole code. I think my problem is more on how to use the useState data for my linechart

Comment: If you want to access the obj like this `data.date` you need object not array, because currently you need to access the data like `data[0].date`, or you need to `.map()` or `.forEach()` the array and get te current element

Comment: Ah thank you so much! Now I see it in the right way :) Would you know what I can use to use it in my chart? Should I use the `.map()` as well? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that type of charts that you are trying to render, also take a look at `Drew Reese` answear.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with both your data and how you are parsing it.

1. The data isn't comma delineated.
2. The date format you are trying to use has the units in reverse order and the dates are not zero-padded.

The data should actually use comma separated columns:

Data.csv

```
Date,Value1,Value2
2020/7/20,1,4
2020/7/21,2,8
2020/7/22,3,10
2020/7/23,4,12
2020/7/24,5,67
2020/7/25,6,10
```

Ensure there is also no trailing whitespace at the end of each line.

The format you should use to parse the date is `"%Y/%m/%d"`.

```
const getCSVData = async () => {
  const tempData = [];

  await d3.csv(
    csvFile,
    function (d) {
      tempData.push({
        date: d3.timeParse("%Y/%m/%d")(d.Date),
        value1: Number(d.Value1),
        value2: Number(d.Value2)
      });
    }
  );

  setData(tempData);
};
```

[image: Edit react-javascript-saving-values-from-local-csv-into-usestate-useeffect]

[image]

Comment: Hi Drew ! Thank you for your answer. I don't really understand your answer though. I'm saving it as a csv file (comma delimited) and the order of the date is the way that I saved it?

Comment: @user2133561 I was only going by what you provided as the "CSV" file in your post, which is quite literally ***not*** separated by any commas. I've only mentioned it and the whitespace since that is what I had to fix in the data you shared to get the `d3.csv()` call to work and parse the file.